# failed to create swapchain with validation layer

Tags: android, validation, vulkan

I tried vulkan + android developed in android studio.
I found good code to be studied in Github https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials.

In chapter2, the site show to introduce calidation layer.

In chapter4, the way of creating a simple blue window is written.

A problem was occured at the step of creating swapchain when introducing validation layer(chapter2 method) to chapter4. Without validation layer, I can create swapchain and display window.

Does anybody know why this error happens? I can not come up with a solution at all why including library and using validation layer trigger error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You probably need to activate validation layers upon VkInstance creation.